# Передача объекта класса из одного Fragment в другой

Tags: android, android-fragment, fragment-transaction

У меня есть два Fragmenta sollveClasssFragment и History_fargment в tabitem каждый. Я хочу передать объект класса History history, который является Serializable.

В sollveClasssFragment я применяю следующий код в методе onCreateView :

```
FragmentTransaction ft =  Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                History_fargment history_fragment = new History_fargment();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                History history;
                history = new History(repl,hdif,dTarg,xT,yT);
                bundle.putSerializable("history", history);
                history_fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                ft.replace(android.R.id.content, history_fragment);
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.commit();
```

В History_fargment я принимаю объект класса в методе onCreate:

```
Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        assert bundle != null;
        History history;
        history = (History) bundle.getSerializable("history");
        lstHistory.add(history);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

Но при запуске sollveClasssFragment появляется ошибка 
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.Serializable android.os.Bundle.getSerializable(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference`

в строке  History_fargment

```
history = (History) bundle.getSerializable("history")
```

Помогите советом пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Передача объектов между фрагментами не должна происходить напрямую! Фрагменты должны быть независимы друг от друга, а это означает что фрагмент "А" ничего не должен знать о фрагменте "Б", а тем более туда что-то передавать.

Все взаимодействие между фрагментами должно проходить через активити в которой они лежат. А фрагменты должны сообщать активити о происходящих событиях через интерфейс. Например: Пользователь кликнул во фрагменте "А" на кнопку "Открыть фрагмент Б". Фрагмент "А" через интерфейс сообщает активити, что произошло событие "Нажатие на кнопку", а активити решает сама что с этим делать.

Что вы получите таким путем? Ваши фрагменты будут переиспользуемы, вы можете например на телефоне иметь 2 фрагмента на 2 экрана, а на планшете 2 фрагмента на одном экране (например почтовое приложение: Фрагмент "А" список писем, фрагмент "Б" детали письма). Так же такое взаимодействие намного легче поддерживать при росте приложения.

Теперь второй вопрос: Как передать?

Передавать через интенты большие объекты не является хорошей практикой, ко всему тому еще и размер бандла ограничен. Чтоб решить эту проблему вам хорошо бы создать сущность которая живет отдельно от фрагмента. Это может быть база данных или просто какой-то синглтон который живет отдельно от фрагментов, а в бандл класть только id (или другой опозновательный параметр, но простой), а при входе на новый фрагмент дергать по id нужный вам объект.